# Is the order of elliptic curve the same as the order of point on it in finite field?

Tags: elliptic-curves

The question is the same as: is elliptic curve cyclic? how to prove it?

**update**

Seems the above answer is no.

But I've a further question(maybe should post another thread?).

Is there a bounding for the order of a random point on an elliptic curve? Many zero knowledge algorithms choose a point randomly, I guess there should be a low limit ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134393/discussion-on-question-by-omg-is-the-order-of-elliptic-curve-the-same-as-the-ord).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to produce random points of large order, the standard approach is to use a fixed, known curve of prime order (which is then guaranteed to be cyclic), and choose random points on that curve.

Do not fix a point $P$ and then choose random integers $k$ and output $kP$, as suggested in one of the comments. This approach is insecure for many protocols.

A definitive resource for this topic is [How to hash into elliptic curves](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/226.pdf) by Icart, published in CRYPTO 2009.

Comment: Can you briefly tell why is it insecure?

Comment: [Random point on the curve](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/68601/18298)

Comment: Consider BLS signatures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLS_digital_signature). You are supposed to hash the message $m$ to a point $h$ and output the signature $h^x$. Suppose instead that you hash the message to a point $g^k$ where $k = H(m)$. Then any party can forge the signature of $m$ by outputting $z^k$ where $z = g^x$ is the public key.